Date as random effect in mixed model strongly changes coefficient estimates
I am struggling with the structure of a mixed model that I run with lme4.
I have measured a behaviour (let's say reaction time) and another variable that might impact it (let's call it "mood, which is measured on a scale from 0 to 1). I measured this in 10 individuals every fourth day over a period of about 4 month. All individuals were measured every day (pretty much - just some individuals drop out earlier than others). And it's not just one data point per ID/per day, but actually a few hundred data points, as it was obtained by continuous monitoring.
I did not really expect an effect of time (date), but was inclined to "control" for some variation therein anyway, hence why I tried adding it as a random effect.
Now what happened, that was unexpected to me, is that the effect of mood on reaction time was very strong initially, but completely disappeared when I added date. I have never seen a random effect alter the estimate of a coefficient by that much, and I am really struggling to comprehend why this is happening.
I cannot share the data unfortunately and thus the details are made up now, but I am trying to use the sleepstudy data, to illustrate my model structure.
# adding the mood variable to it:
sleepstudy$mood <-  rnorm(180, mean = 0.6, sd = 0.15)
# and also fitting a quadratic realtionship
sleepstudy$mood2 <- sleepstudy$mood^2

# fitting the model:
model <-lmer(Reaction  ~ mood + mood2 + (1 | Subject)  + (1 | Days), data = sleepstudy)

So when I fit this model with my actual data (variables there renamed to fit the example), this is the output I get for the model without the random effect of Days:
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: Reaction ~ mood + mood2 + (1 | Subject)
   Data: studyData

REML criterion at convergence: 1049575

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.8816 -0.6241 -0.0833  0.5268  8.1988 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Subject  (Intercept) 111.8    10.57   
 Residual             675.7    25.99   
Number of obs: 112205, groups:  Subject, 9

Fixed effects:
              Estimate Std. Error         df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)     12.844      3.651      9.158   3.518  0.00637 ** 
mood            77.045      3.263 112198.749  23.613  < 2e-16 ***
mood2          -53.922      2.687 112197.946 -20.065  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
      (Intr) mood  
mood  -0.256       
mood2  0.246 -0.988

and this is what it changes to, when I add days:
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: Reaction ~ mood + mood2 + (1 | Subject) + (1 | Days)
   Data: studyData

REML criterion at convergence: 1018994

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.8348 -0.6387 -0.1259  0.4744  9.4342 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Days     (Intercept) 265.58   16.297  
 Subject  (Intercept)  92.37    9.611  
 Residual             513.64   22.664  
Number of obs: 112205, groups:  Days, 26; Subject, 9

Fixed effects:
               Estimate  Std. Error          df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)     37.6287      4.6169     26.0857   8.150 1.22e-08 ***
mood             2.3961      3.0378 112183.5499   0.789    0.430    
mood2           -0.7413      2.4628 112180.6597  -0.301    0.763    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
      (Intr) mood  
mood  -0.192       
mood2  0.185 -0.988 

So my question would be what could cause this strong change, what can I do to explore it further, and most importantly, which is the correct version of the model?
I did plot the variables over time, but there is no strong obvious trend that I could spot. Any help here would be very appreciated. Thanks.
Edit:
The random effects of my actual data look like that:
> ranef(model)
$Days
           (Intercept)
2023-03-10   -8.058675
2023-03-14    4.420770
2023-03-22   -1.241021
2023-03-30   -1.842376
2023-04-03   -4.123564
2023-04-11  -24.156998
2023-04-15  -21.530589
2023-04-19  -29.677679
2023-04-23  -49.154192
2023-04-27   18.953294
2023-05-01   12.366573
2023-05-05   14.597689
2023-05-09   18.638003
2023-05-13   10.843020
2023-05-17   17.950115
2023-05-21    8.866660
2023-05-25   -1.328025
2023-05-29   -5.459518
2023-06-02   -4.203232
2023-06-06    6.116818
2023-06-10   11.951629
2023-06-14   12.959638
2023-06-18    7.703864
2023-06-22   -3.090827
2023-06-26    1.892723
2023-06-30    6.605902

$Subject
        (Intercept)
S1    -11.072005
S2      9.077030
S3     11.399909
S4     -3.879497
S5     -5.786223
S6   -14.718197
S7    -1.734189
S8     7.694324
S9     9.018848

UPDATE:
Now another very strange thing is happening when I added Days as a fixed effect. That is, that it brought the intercept to a very odd value value (-2554) that is completely off the range where any off my values lie. And this is only resulting from the addition of date, when I remove it from the model the intercept is 13 again. How does this make any sense?!
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Subject  (Intercept)  95.14    9.754  
 Residual             660.58   25.702  
Number of obs: 112205, groups:  Subject, 9

Fixed effects:
              Estimate Std. Error         df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -2.554e+03  5.077e+01  9.011e+04 -50.299  < 2e-16 ***
mood         2.481e+01  3.387e+00  1.122e+05   7.326 2.38e-13 ***
mood2       -1.715e+01  2.754e+00  1.122e+05  -6.228 4.75e-10 ***
Days         1.595e-06  3.147e-08  1.122e+05  50.665  < 2e-16 ***


Regarding the update: (1) This may be normal, depending on how Days is encoded. Remember that the intercept is just a theoretical value of the outcome if you were to set all explanatory variables to zero. That is not always a meaningful value on its own, for example if day 0 is somewhere in 1970 where you don't have any data. (2) It is better to ask follow-up questions as separate posts.

If you want to take into account the effect of time, you should do so by including a fixed effect. Using a common rule of thumb: Days cannot be reasonably assumed to come from some larger population of days you could have randomly picked. Subjects can.
Suppose there is some learning effect, where the outcome gradually changes over time from repeated measurement. This effect is fixed, because it would happen again, similarly, were you to repeat the experiment. The subjects, however, would be different ones.
You can even see that this is the case in your example by inspecting the estimated random effect. Note how the offsets for the subjects look like a random draw, whereas days are suspiciously ordered low to high:
ranef(model)
# $Subject
#     (Intercept)
# 308  40.0514369
# 309 -77.5458872
# 310 -64.0565849
# 330   3.0187945
# 331   8.8622398
# 332   6.6438080
# 333  15.8984897
# 334  -0.9616104
# 335 -47.2424259
# 337  71.7806484
# 349 -18.9409350
# 350  14.7350720
# 351  -7.2637022
# 352  34.0969298
# 369   8.9157689
# 370  -4.5692638
# 371  -1.9386011
# 372  18.5158223
# 
# $Days
#   (Intercept)
# 0  -39.131512
# 1  -34.327996
# 2  -30.930363
# 3  -14.476669
# 4   -9.377897
# 5   10.326851
# 6   11.946196
# 7   20.648729
# 8   36.186700
# 9   49.135960

(Your numbers will differ because you did not use a seed in the example provided.)

PS: It is better to used the poly function for a quadratic effect:
library("lme4")
library("splines")
lmer(Reaction ~ ns(Days, 3) + poly(mood, 2) + (1 | Subject), data = sleepstudy)

This creates orthogonal polynomial contrasts. Alternatively, you can fit a regression spline, as is shown for Days here.

Thanks, the explanation with date as fixed effects makes sense. Though, would it still apply to my actual data set, where (unlike in the example I've provided) the dates don't look ordered? I have just added them to my question above.
The other point is, that I am actually not even interested in the effect of date from my question, and was rather wondering if I had to include it, because I was sampling data over a longer period, and because there obviously is some natural variation... or if I could also just not add it.

(1) If you believe the effect of Days to be substantial, you should include it in the model, regardless of whether you are interested in it, because it may confound the effect of mood.
(2) Try plotting your random effect for Days and you'll see it's very non-random. It almost looks like there is some sort of cyclic pattern. If you want to include its effect, you could perhaps try a periodic spline, but I recommend creating a separate question for that, because it is quite different from the example you gave.

Thanks. There is absolutely no reason for my measurement to appear in a cyclic pattern. I think the variation is really just random. The measurements were taken from animals in the wild and the variation might just be linked to environmental factors that I am not accounting for. So I think I will just add date as a fixed effect to the model, if this makes more sense than adding it as a random one..

It certainly makes sense to go beyond a simple linear fit for time as a fixed effect. Using a regression spline to model time could be even better than the quadratic polynomial that's proposed; that can cover a wider variety of time dependences.

@EdM Maybe I misunderstand, but a quadratic effect of time is not suggested by the OP, nor by me. It was a comment regarding the creation of mood2 as the square of mood and including that in the model. I will change the linear effect of Days to a spline in the answer for clarity.

@FransRodenburg yes, I misread your answer the first time.
